# Need help writing SQL SELECT statement that combines two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: team and team_member.  The team_member table shows which user is a member of which team.

```
+---------+------------+
| team_id |    name    |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | Marketing  |
|       2 | New Launch |
|       3 | Sales      |
+---------+------------+

+---------+---------+  
| user_id | team_id |  
+---------+---------+  
|      21 |       2 |  
|    4369 |       1 |  
|    4369 |       2 |  
|    4369 |       3 |  
|     100 |       1 |  
|      21 |       1 | 
+---------+---------+
```

I need a query that tells me the team_id and team name for all teams that a given user_id is a member of and also (here's the difficult part) a count of all members in each team.

For the above data, if we're looking at user 21, I expect to see the following output because user 21 is a member of team 1 and team 2 and team 1 has 3 members and team 2 has 2 members.

```
+---------+------------+-------+
| team_id |    name    | count |
+---------+------------+-------+
|       1 | Marketing  |     3 |
|       2 | New Launch |     2 |
+---------+------------+-------+
```

Any idea how I can do this in SQL (MySQL preferably if that makes a difference)?  Getting the first 2 columns is no problem (see bottom) but I can't figure out how to add the count.  Thanks!

```
SELECT team.team_id, team.name
FROM team
LEFT JOIN team_member ON team.team_id = team_member.team_id
WHERE team_member.user_id = 21
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join `team_member` twice with `team` and then aggregate:

```
SELECT t.team_id, t.name, COUNT(mm.user_id) count
FROM team_member m
INNER JOIN team t ON t.team_id = m.team_id
INNER JOIN team_member mm ON mm.team_id = t.team_id
WHERE m.user_id = 21
GROUP BY t.team_id, t.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k9sBDKfZqzNzPPqnGLmd5D/0).
Results:

```
| team_id | name       | count |
| ------- | ---------- | ----- |
| 1       | Marketing  | 3     |
| 2       | New Launch | 2     |
```

Comment: I'm getting a headache trying to visualize joining a table with itself but this answer looks best.  Thank you.

Comment: Self joins are common practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT team.team_id, team.name, count(team_member.team_id)
FROM team
INNER JOIN team_member ON team.team_id = team_member.team_id
GROUP BY (team.team_id, team.name)
WHERE team_member.user_id = 21
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pivot query.

```
SELECT t.team_id,
       MAX(IF(m.user_id = 21, t.name,  NULL)) AS name,
       COUNT(m.user_id) AS count
FROM team t
JOIN team_member m ON t.team_id = m.team_id
GROUP BY t.team_id
HAVING name IS NOT NULL
```

Only generate the team name column from the aggregate data if 21 is found on the team.

Output:

```
team_id |    name    | count
   1    | Marketing  |   3
   2    | New Launch |   2
```

Answer (score -1):

Do count(teamid) then group by name or teamid, then you will need to do having instead of where to filter by teamid or name.